# Reading and displaying the datatypes of data in a text file

Tags: vbscript

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set Note = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\VB Script Trying\textdata.txt", 1)

Do Until Note.AtEndOfStream
    'Textline = Note.Readline()
    WScript.Echo(VarType(Split(Note.Readline, " ")(1))) 'Dynamically Checked
Loop
```

The above code is simple, I read from a file and have to display the datatypes for each word/number in a text file.

This the content:

```
( Hai 1.2 1000 a b c )
```

The code runs only "Hai", it wont display the next words or numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Your Split returns an array. You select the SECOND element of your zero-based array here `Split(Note.Readline, " ")(1)` and get it's vartype. You are actually getting the VarType of your `1.2` in your array... so not each element, and not the first item `Hai` as that would be at `Split(Note.Readline, " ")(0)`

To get the vartype of each element then iterate your array:

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set Note = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\VB Script Trying\textdata.txt", 1)

Do Until Note.AtEndOfStream

    'Textline = Note.Readline()
    For Each elem in Split(Note.Readline, " ")
        WScript.Echo(elem & ": " & VarType(elem))
    Next elem

Loop
```

The rub here is that an array is typed and since you don't declare this array but poof it out of a string with the `Split()` function it may just decide that the vartype of each `elem` is a string, but I haven't tested so perhaps it will spit out the expected type.